# Replace hash values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash like this:

```
 a = {"note_id"=>[nil, 1], "comment_id"=>[nil, 4]}

 a = {"note_id"=>[1, 3], "comment_id"=>[4, 5]}

 a = {"note_id"=>[3, nil], "comment_id"=>[5, nil]}
```

I want to changes note_id values from [nil, 1] to [nil, 8]  or [1, 3] to [8, 7]
similarly with comment_id also.

If values will be nil, then I don't want to update any things on that place.

For this I am doing like this:

```
if a.include? 'note_id' || 'comment_id'
   a[:note_id].each do |k| 
      k = object.method1 
   end
   a[:comment_id].each do |k| 
      k = object.method2
   end
end
```

But the note_id and comment_id values are remain same.

Could someone please help me on that.

Comment: What exactly is an object in above logic?

Comment: object is user and in user model I have one method. that returns some integer value.

Comment: So you want the array values to be modified to `object.method1` right?

Comment: If you had `a = {"note_id"=>[nil, 1]}` would you want the each loop to run on the a[:note_id] array? (Same question for `a = {"comment_id"=>[nil, 4]}` but with a[:comment_id]).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going wrong here:

1. You have string keys in the `Hash` and later reference them as symbols in `a[:note_id]`.
2. `if a.include? 'note_id' || 'comment_id'` is effectively `if a.include? 'note_id'`
3. When enumerating the `Array` with `each` you loose the reference to the position in the array and you get only the element stored in variable `k`. Therefore `k=` modifies only the variable in that scope. However if you modify the element of the `a["note_id"]` it will reflect the change into `a` since by calling `a["note_id"]` you get a reference to the same `Array` object as is stored in the `Hash`

```rb
require "ostruct"
object = OpenStruct.new({method1: 11, method2: 12})
a = {"note_id" => [nil, 1], "comment_id" => [nil, 4]}
#=> {"note_id"=>[nil, 1], "comment_id"=>[nil, 4]}
if (['note_id', 'comment_id'] - a.keys).empty?
   a["note_id"].each_with_index do |v,i|
      a["note_id"][i] = object.method1 unless v.nil?
   end
   a["comment_id"].each_with_index do |v,i| 
      a["comment_id"][i] = object.method2 unless v.nil?
   end
end
a
#=> {"note_id"=>[nil, 11], "comment_id"=>[nil, 12]}
```

Edit: addressed the issue with `a.include?` condition; updated the code so that it does not update `nil` values

Comment: `a.include? 'note_id' || 'comment_id'` is probably problematic too.

Comment: @BenStephens Yes, I missed that. However it should be an easy fix for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
if a.include? 'note_id' || 'comment_id'
  a[:note_id] = a[:note_id].map do |k| 
     object.method1 if k!= nil
  end
  a[:comment_id]  = a[:comment_id].map do |k| 
     object.method2 if k!= nil
  end
end
```